# Topics in Algebra, 2nd Ed, Section 2.5, Problem 6.C

Tags: group-theory

I'm lost. Completely. Please help

Write out all the right cosets of $H$ in $G$ where $G = A(S);\;\; S = \{x_1,\ x_2,\ x_3\};\;\; H = \{σ \in G:\;\; x_1 σ = x_1\}.$

Answer (score 1):

$A(S)$ means the [alternating group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) of the set $S$ which is a subgroup of the *symmetric group* of $S$. 
Hence, the elements of $G$ are (even) *permutations* of the $3$ element set $S=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, and a permutation $\sigma$ belongs to $H$ iff it *fixes* the element $x_1$, i.e. $x_1\sigma=x_1$. (It might be unusual that the action of the permutation is written on the *right* to its argument: instead of $\sigma(x_1)$ it is written $x_1\sigma$ here.)

Now, the symmetric group has $3!=6$ elements, half of them are even, so there are only $3$ elements of $A(S)$, namely the identity ${\rm id}$, and the two 3-cycles $(x_1\,x_2\,x_3)$ and $(x_1\,x_3\,x_2)$, call them $\alpha$ and $\beta$. 
[Remark: check that all other permutations consists of odd numbers of transpositions.]

Can you conclude then which of the three elements of $A(S)$ belong to $H$ and what are the sets $H\alpha$, $\ H\beta\,$?

Comment: No, I'm still lost. Sorry. This is still very abstract for me. Could you break it all down to small bits. I'm getting killed in this class.

Comment: Ok. So, $G=A(S)$ contains *permutations* of the 3 element set $S$. There are only $6$ such permutations. Can you write all of them up? (E.g. we have the 'transposition' that swaps $x_1$ and $x_3$, denoted by $(x_1\,x_3)\ $ [i.e. as a cycle of length $2$], or we have the cycle $(x_1\,x_2\,x_3)$ that takes $x_1$ to $x_2$, $\ x_2$ to $x_3$, and $\,x_3$ to $x_1$, cyclically.) Which ones of the permutations do belong to the alternating group $A(S)$? If you're there, reread my answer.

Comment: @Berci so only the identity element fixes $x_1$ and therefore $A(S)$ has just one element?